# Compute the sum of variables in data frames allocated in a list in R considering differents conditions over others variables

Tags: r, plyr, lapply

Hi everybody I am working with a list of data frames in R. Lists are awesome in R but I want to solve this. I have a list named `global` that has five data frames `f1,f2,f3,f4,f5` each data frame has a principal variable named `CreditValue` and variables that works like flags for example `f1` has `CreditValue` and a flag variable `b1` with values of 1. `f2` has two flag variables `b1` with values of 1 and `b2` with values of 2. `f3` hast three flag variables `b1` with values of 1, `b2` with values of 2 and `b3` with values of 3. `f4` has four flag variables `b1` with values of 1, `b2` with values of 2 ,`b3` with values of 3 and `b4` with values of 4. `f5` has five flag variables `b1` with values of 1, `b2` with values of 2 ,`b3` with values of 3, `b4` with values of 4 and `b5` with values of 5. Flag variables always start in column 3 for all data frames. I wish to compute the sum of `CreditValue` in each data frame considering different aspects over flag variables. My list has the next structure (I include `dput` version in the final part):

```
global
$f1
  KeyID CreditValue b1
1   001           1  1
2   002           2  1
3   003           3  1
4   004           4  1
5   005           5  1
6   006           6  1
7   007           7  1
8   009           8  1
9   010           9  1

$f2
   KeyID CreditValue b1 b2
1    001           1  1  2
2    002           2  1  2
3    003           3 NA  2
4    004           4 NA  2
5    005           5 NA  2
6    006           6  1  2
7    007           7  1  2
8    009           8 NA  2
9    010           9  1  2
10   011          10 NA  2
11   012          11  1  2

$f3
   KeyID CreditValue b1 b2 b3
1    001           1  1  2  3
2    002           2  1  2  3
3    003           3  1  2  3
4    004           4  1  2  3
5    005           5 NA  2  3
6    006           6 NA  2  3
7    007           7  1  2  3
8    009           8  1  2  3
9    010           9 NA NA  3
10   011          10 NA NA  3
11   012          11 NA  2  3
12   013          11  1  2  3
13   014          11 NA NA  3

$f4
   KeyID CreditValue b1 b2 b3 b4
1    001           1 NA  2  3  4
2    002           2 NA  2  3  4
3    003           3 NA NA NA  4
4    004           4 NA NA NA  4
5    005           5 NA NA NA  4
6    006           6  1  2  3  4
7    007           7  1  2  3  4
8    009           8  1  2  3  4
9    010           9  1  2  3  4
10   011          10  1  2  3  4
11   012          11  1  2  3  4
12   013          11  1  2  3  4
13   014          11  1  2  3  4
14   015          12  1 NA  3  4
15   016          12  1 NA  3  4

$f5
   KeyID CreditValue b1 b2 b3 b4 b5
1    001           1  1  2  3  4  5
2    002           2  1  2  3  4  5
3    003           3  1  2  3  4  5
4    004           4  1  2  3  4  5
5    005           5 NA NA  3  4  5
6    006           6  1  2  3  4  5
7    007           7  1  2  3  4  5
8    009           8  1  2  3  4  5
9    010           9  1  2  3  4  5
10   011          10 NA NA NA NA  5
11   012          11  1  2  3  4  5
12   013          11  1  2  3  4  5
13   014          11  1  2  3  4  5
14   015          12  1  2  3  4  5
15   016          12  1  2  3  4  5
16   017          14 NA NA NA  4  5
17   018          14 NA NA NA  4  5
```

I have used `llply()` function form `plyr` package to work with lists in R but I don't know how to define a function to make this. I compute the sums using this code but if I had more data frames it would be so complex. Also I would like to save this values in a new data frame or matrix considering flag variables (5). The results of the sums are the next:

```
sum(f1$CreditValue[f1[,3]==1])
[1] 45
sum(f2$CreditValue[f2[,3]==1],na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 36
sum(f3$CreditValue[f3[,3]==1],na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 36
sum(f4$CreditValue[f4[,3]==1],na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 97
sum(f5$CreditValue[f5[,3]==1],na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 97
```

These sums are computed applying those formulas considering `b1` variable in all data frames.

```
sum(f2$CreditValue[is.na(f2[,3]) & f2[,4]==2] ,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 30
sum(f3$CreditValue[is.na(f3[,3]) & f3[,4]==2] ,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 22
sum(f4$CreditValue[is.na(f4[,3]) & f4[,4]==2] ,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 3
sum(f5$CreditValue[is.na(f5[,3]) & f5[,4]==2] ,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 0
```

These sums are computed applying those formulas considering values of `b2` and `b1` variables in all data frames. Here there is a condition over values of `b1` (column 3).

```
sum(f3$CreditValue[is.na(f3[,3]) & is.na(f3[,4]) & f3[,5]==3] ,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 30
sum(f4$CreditValue[is.na(f4[,3]) & is.na(f4[,4]) & f4[,5]==3] ,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 0
sum(f5$CreditValue[is.na(f5[,3]) & is.na(f5[,4]) & f5[,5]==3] ,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 5
```

These sums are computed applying those formulas considering values of `b3`, `b2` and `b1` variables in all data frames. Now there is a condition over values of `b1` and `b2` (columns 3, 4).

```
sum(f4$CreditValue[is.na(f4[,3]) & is.na(f4[,4]) & is.na(f4[,5]) & f4[,6]==4] ,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 12
sum(f5$CreditValue[is.na(f5[,3]) & is.na(f5[,4]) & is.na(f5[,5]) & f5[,6]==4] ,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 28
```

These sums are computed applying those formulas considering values of `b4`, `b3`, `b2` and `b1` variables in all data frames. Now there is a condition over values of `b1`, `b2` and `b3` (columns 3, 4, 5).

```
sum(f5$CreditValue[is.na(f5[,3]) & is.na(f5[,4]) & is.na(f5[,5]) & is.na(f5[,6]) & f5[,7]==5] ,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 10
```

This sum is computed applying last formula considering values of `b5`, `b4`, `b3`, `b2` and `b1` variables in all data frames. Now there is a condition over values of `b1`, `b2`, `b3` and `b4` (columns 3, 4, 5, 6).

The showed sum are the result of a lot of code but I would like to create a function that works over flag variables (`b1, b2, b3, b4, b5`) to compute the sums. I don't know if it is possible to make this with a `for` or a function that works with `llply` or `lapply`. I have tried to resume code like this:

```
sum(f5$CreditValue[is.na(f5[,3]) & is.na(f5[,4]) & is.na(f5[,5]) & is.na(f5[,6]) & f5[,7]==5] ,na.rm=TRUE)
```

With this code:

```
sum(f5$CreditValue[is.na(f5[,3,4,5,6]) & f5[,7]==5] ,na.rm=TRUE)
```

But it doesn't job because with the original conditions I am considering only specific rows in each data frame and the resumed code doesn't make this. I would like to save the results of sums in a new data frame, matrix like this:

```
    f1  f2  f3  f4  f5
f1  45  0   0   0   0
f2  36  30  0   0   0
f3  36  22  30  0   0
f4  97  3   0   12  0
f5  97  0   5   28  10
```

The zeros in the last data frame are produced due to all data frames don't have all flag variables for example `f1` only has `b1` and it doesn't have `b2,b3,b4,b5` like `f5`. The `dput` version of my list is the next:

```
structure(list(f1 = structure(list(KeyID = c("001", "002", "003", 
"004", "005", "006", "007", "009", "010"), CreditValue = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), b1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("KeyID", 
"CreditValue", "b1"), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame"), 
    f2 = structure(list(KeyID = c("001", "002", "003", "004", 
    "005", "006", "007", "009", "010", "011", "012"), CreditValue = c(1, 
    2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), b1 = c(1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
    1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1), b2 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2)), .Names = c("KeyID", "CreditValue", "b1", "b2"), row.names = c(NA, 
    11L), class = "data.frame"), f3 = structure(list(KeyID = c("001", 
    "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "009", "010", "011", 
    "012", "013", "014"), CreditValue = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
    8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 11), b1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, 
    NA, NA, 1, NA), b2 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA, NA, 2, 
    2, NA), b3 = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)), .Names = c("KeyID", 
    "CreditValue", "b1", "b2", "b3"), row.names = c(NA, 13L), class = "data.frame"), 
    f4 = structure(list(KeyID = c("001", "002", "003", "004", 
    "005", "006", "007", "009", "010", "011", "012", "013", "014", 
    "015", "016"), CreditValue = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
    10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12), b1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), b2 = c(2, 2, NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA, NA), b3 = c(3, 3, NA, NA, NA, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), b4 = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4)), .Names = c("KeyID", "CreditValue", "b1", 
    "b2", "b3", "b4"), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame"), 
    f5 = structure(list(KeyID = c("001", "002", "003", "004", 
    "005", "006", "007", "009", "010", "011", "012", "013", "014", 
    "015", "016", "017", "018"), CreditValue = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 
    5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 14, 14), b1 = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA), b2 = c(2, 
    2, 2, 2, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA, NA), b3 = c(3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, NA, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, NA, NA), b4 = c(4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, NA, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), b5 = c(5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)), .Names = c("KeyID", 
    "CreditValue", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5"), row.names = c(NA, 
    17L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("f1", "f2", "f3", 
"f4", "f5"))
```

I hope you can help me it is so complex for me building a function to compute the sums and If I use traditional forms of code I would have problems with lists of more data frames. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lapply and call a function that builds the rows of your output data frame:

```
get.sums = function(df) {
  sapply(1:5, function(y) {
    if (y > 1) {
      na.col = 3:(y+1)
    } else {
      na.col = NULL
    }
    if (paste0("b", y) %in% names(df)) {
      return(sum(df$CreditValue[rowSums(!is.na(df[,na.col,drop=F])) == 0 & df[,(y+2)] == y], na.rm=T))
    } else {
      return(0)
    }
  })
}
rows = lapply(global, get.sums)
sums = do.call(rbind, rows)
sums
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# f1   45    0    0    0    0
# f2   36   30    0    0    0
# f3   36   22   30    0    0
# f4   97    3    0   12    0
# f5   97    0    5   28   10
```